# Rest API handling enum deserializaton errors

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

We have a basic RESTful API to support a frontend, implemented using Spring Boot.

One of our user data objects has some enums:

```
enum ColorScheme {
  RED,
  BLUE
}
```

We just use this as an attribute in our domain object.

```
class User {
  @NotNull(message = "A color scheme is required.")
  ColorScheme colorScheme;
  //...
}
```

and accept it as a `@RequestBody` in our REST controller.

As you can see we are also using Hibernate validation annotations that generate a friendly JSON response with errors pulled from the annotations.

However, when I pass a value other than `RED` or `BLUE`, the controller method doesn't even fire; an exception is generated earlier in the request chain, and returned to the user.

```
{
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message": "Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize value of type ColorTheme from String \"FooBar\": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [RED, BLUE]\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@52b4d811; line: 1, column: 51] (through reference chain: .... snip ...",
    "path": "/rest/foo/bar",
    "status": 400,
    "timestamp": 1498842705459
}
```

I don't want the stack trace to be sent back to the user! I want a human readable response.

I was thinking about catching this by implementing Controller Advice for `HttpMessageNotReadableException` but I feel as though this catches too many other potential cases.

Could someone help me untangle this? What's an elegant way to do this in Spring?

Comment: Controller Advice is good practice. You should have custom handlers for some certain types of exceptions but in general, you should have a method that handles Exception itself with general "We are sorry" message, in case a weird exception is thrown and you wouldn't want to send your stacktrace to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, no pun intended!